Nextui accordion divider weight
When I have a nextui accordion, the second divider always has a bigger weight than the first. Im not applying a special style or anything to the dividers, and its always just the second one. When ther's 5 items in the accordion, just the second divider has a bigger weight.
Divider pictured here
Accordion code:
<Accordion variant="shadow" className="" selectedKeys={selectedKeys} onSelectionChange={setSelectedKeys}>
  {getCharacters(characters)}
</Accordion>

Accordion Item code:
<AccordionItem key={`${i}`} aria-label={`${character.name}`} title={<p
className="text-base">
  {`${character.name}`}
  </p>
  } >
  <div className="flex flex-col">
    <p className="mb-2">
      {character.desc}
    </p>
    <h1 className="text-lg mb-2">
      Vlastnosti
    </h1>
    <Code color="primary" className="text-wrap whitespace-normal text-primary mb-3">
      {formatArrayToString(character.attributes)}
    </Code>
  </div>
</AccordionItem>

Does anyone know why this is happening?
